# How to avoid by accepting 2 values for Select field in RJSF form?

Tags: reactjs, select, schema, antd

In react app, I am using `rjsf` library for form fields. Also I am using `ant design`.

```
"@rjsf/antd": "^5.8.1",
"@rjsf/core": "^5.5.2",
"@rjsf/utils": "^5.5.2",
"@rjsf/validator-ajv8": "5.6.2",
"antd": "^5.6.3",
```

I have added a  field like,

```
    ...uiSchema,
    cityId: {
      "ui:widget": "select",
      "ui:enumOptions": list.map((c) => ({
        value: c.id,
        label: c.name,
      })),
      "ui:options": {
        multiple: false,
      },
    },
  };
```

Here, even after adding `multiple: false` I am able to select more than 1 values.

How can I make it as accepts only single value?